# jQuery Mobile listview, Adding vote buttons to a line item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to add 2 vote buttons to the left hand side of a jQuery mobile listview. The vote buttons should be centered in the list item, and should be on the left-hand side.

I have sort of gotten this to work using javascript, but what I really want to do is to get this to work without any additional javascript and use the standard jquery mobile data-role attributes and enhancement with pure HTML & CSS.

Here is the HTML markup that I would like to use:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul class="has-vote-btns" data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <h3>Line Item</h3>
                    <p>Sub title</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" data-icon="bars"></a>
                <a href="#" class="vote-btn like-btn" data-icon="arrow-u" title="Like"></a>
                <a href="#" class="vote-btn dislike-btn" data-icon="arrow-d" title="Dislike"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.vote-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.vote-btn .ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 0;
}
.like-btn {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.dislike-btn {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.has-vote-btns .ui-link-inherit {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
}
.has-vote-btns .ui-li-has-thumb .ui-link-inherit {
    padding-left: 118px !important;
}
```

This does not work ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/b6n5G/)).

I was, however, able to get it to work but only by removing the 2 vote buttons in the HTML markup and then adding some javascript to add the buttons dynamically after the listview has already enhanced.

Here the javascript I added to make it work ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/b6n5G/1/)):

```
$(function(){
    $('.has-vote-btns').each(function() {
        $(this).find('li').each(function(i, li){
            $('<a href="#" class="vote-btn like-btn" title="Like"></a>').buttonMarkup({
                icon: 'arrow-u',
                iconpos: 'notext'
            }).appendTo(li);
            $('<a href="#" class="vote-btn dislike-btn" title="Dislike"></a>').buttonMarkup({
                icon: 'arrow-d',
                iconpos: 'notext'
            }).appendTo(li);
        });
    });
});
```

But this second approach of adding the 2 vote buttons after the enhancement is inconvenient. It would be much better if I could do this with plain HTML and CSS rather than hacking in those buttons after the enhancement.

Is there any solution to this that does not use javascript to insert the vote buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have updated your first fiddle with a CSS only solution:

> **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/b6n5G/4/)**

It is not the only way to do this, but I believe it solves your issue.

The `<ul>` HTML is changed as follows:

```
<ul class="has-vote-btns" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="bars" data-split-theme="d">
    <li> 
        <a href="#">
            <h3>Line Item 1</h3>
            <p>Sub title 1</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="vote-btns"> 
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" title="Like"></a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" title="Dislike"></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I set the data split icon and theme at the `<ul>` level (`data-split-icon="bars" data-split-theme="d"`) and in the `<li>`, I put the voting buttons in their own container so it can be positioned at the left.  Here is the CSS that positions the container and the 2 buttons within the container:

```
.has-vote-btns .ui-link-inherit {
    margin-left: 40px !important;
}
.vote-btns {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 39px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.vote-btns a:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.vote-btns a:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Of course you don't have to use the :first-child and :last-child pseudo selectors; you could use your like-btn and dislike-btn classes...

> Here is an updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/b6n5G/8/)** for jQM 1.4.x